# Ejection Velocity of a CubeSat on Mars?

Tags: cubesat, development

I am trying to decide whether or not I would need to add propulsion systems onto my 3U cubesat if it is being deployed in the Mars atmosphere. From what I've found so far, cubesats are typically deployed using a spring system at 5 cm/s, which makes sense because they are being deployed in space. However, this value probably won't be applicable to a deployment on Mars. Does anyone know of a value for the ejection velocity of a cubesat while not in space or maybe know of a way to figure it out?

Comment: "it is being deployed in the Mars atmosphere" can you expand on this? At what altitude? "while not in space" doesn't make much sense for a cubesat.

Comment: I have never heard of atmospheric or surface cubesats before, and that's such an unusual thing that it almost certainly would be determined by agreement with whatever provider is taking it there.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here. What does "deployed in the Mars atmosphere" mean from an aerodynamic engineering perspective? At what altitude and moving at what speed and in what direction with respect to the direction of motion?